# through the browser a faulty view, nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I want to show page error:

```
else
{
fs.readFile('./template/error.html' ,'utf8', function (err, data)
{
res.write(data, function (err){} );
res.end();
});
```

When I browse a page from the browser **http://localhost:3000/** (the main page)

all content is displayed, but without css and js, and the console shows the error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**

but if i open in the folder: **file:///D:/nodejs/hello-online/template/error.html**

it works great including design, and there are no errors in the console.
why is it happening?

Comment: Add `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});` above of `res.write(data, function (err){} );`

Comment: You have one too many `{` in this code block.

Comment: @MushkaBachar I think you can directly render html using res.render('main.html') because fs is just reading your html file content and if you are using external css or js it won't be rendering the same.

Comment: "why is it happening?" — You're serving up the error.html file again when the browser asks for the CSS or JS.

Comment: @MushkaBachar — Take a look at the duplicate question. (The short answer is "pay attention to what the client asks for and give then that")

Comment: I don't know who I am, sorry                                                                                                               that does not help me                                                                                                                                       I downloaded packs